# Why does Elasticsearch bulk index API creates documents after long time?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I have a Elasticsearch cluster with two nodes. Using Node js bulk insert API, I insert streaming data as batch of 1000 documents per insert using below code,

```
esclient1.bulk({
  body: messages
}, function (err, resp) {
  //handle resp
});
```

The messages gets posted to the server, but the documents gets created only after an hour or two. Don't know why such delay.

There was a total of 2M records split into 1K per bulk insert. Even after 24 hrs the documents are still being indexed. Please let me know where the issue might be.

We use AWS EC2 m3.large (7.5 GB RAM, 32 GB SSD storage) x 2

The Kibana status shows Heap Total (MB) - 652.92 & Heap Used (MB) - 631.56. Is this the cause for slow index creation?

Comment: what does heap total : 652.92  mean ? Is that the heap allocated for the es-instance  on the 7.5GB box ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the `bulk` thread pool, under node stats

http://your_server_id:9200/_nodes/stats/thread_pool

Check the `queue` size there. If you have too many requests in queue then you do not have enough threads to handle all your bulk indexing requests.

The number of threads are allocated based on number of available cpu cores. 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-threadpool.html

> For index/delete operations. Thread pool type is fixed with a
>   size of # of available processors, queue_size of 200.

I would also check indices stats

http://your_server_ip:9200/_nodes/stats/indices

Specifically check the numbers under indexing, merges and segments, and see if anything stands out.